# Load IGC file as Simple Features in R

Tags: r, gps

I have a large number of [IGC files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IGC_(file_format)) that are GPS traces logging paraglider flights.

I'd like to load them as simple features using `sf::st_read()` but the sf library doesn't know how to deal with them. Does anyone know if there's a straightforward solution to loading them? I've written a simple function to parse the logs as they're only text files but I haven't built it to cover the full spec of an IGC file so it gets caught out sometimes.

I can bounce them off gpsbabel and convert them to something sf can read but was hoping there's a nice way to read them straight into R.

`sf::st_read()` returns:

`The source could be corrupt or not supported. See` st_drivers() `for a list of supported formats. In addition: Warning message: In CPL_read_ogr(dsn, layer, query, as.character(options), quiet,  : GDAL Error 1: posix_spawnp() failed`

Comment: perhaps https://rdrr.io/cran/geoviz/man/read_igc.html (not tested by me)

Comment: I built that :) It's OK but not completely reliable because there are bits of the IGC format it can't cope with.

Comment: https://github.com/roh6608/IGC-Analysis-Tools looks promising, but haven't tested it (don't have any IGC file). On the other hand, interesting topic :)

Comment: Played a bit with `IGCparse()` function, the issue is around https://github.com/roh6608/IGC-Analysis-Tools/blob/132b83a6ef01d83d11ae4e9809122f535921d6ae/R/IGCparse.R#L29 as `dplyr::funs()` is obsolete and few lines earlier where `data$lat_min` and `data$lon_min` is calculated, however easy to fix.